# Using JavaScript to create a Chrome-style alert

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup

How do I create an alert in Chrome using JavaScript that opens a text box in the middle of the browser window and washes out the background, like so:

[image: a pretty Chrome alert]

rather than an alert that just pops up an entirely new window (in my case in the Linux Mint GTK theme):

[image: an ugly GTK popup]

If I type `alert()` into the console, I get an alert that looks like the latter, in a separate window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [dialog element](http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/). Something like this:

HTML:

```
<dialog>
  This is a dialog.<br>
  <button>Close</button>
</dialog>
```

Javascript:

```
var dialog = document.querySelector("dialog")
dialog.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  dialog.close()
})
dialog.showModal()
```

Comment: Not a lot of browser support, does work in Chrome. http://caniuse.com/#feat=dialog

Comment: It doesn't need to work in other browsers: the question has the google-chrome-extension tag.

Comment: theres a polyfill anyway in github that works on most browsers